# Limiting text with max height

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel, twig

I have a grid layout where I'd like to limit the height of the text, by cutting the text than adding more... link. I used the length to get where i have to cut the text. But when a post contains short lines and divided with enter than they count as a short text but their height is still high.
like this:

```
----------  ----------
|12345678|  |12      |
|9more...|  |34      |
|        |  |56      |
----------  |78      |
            |9more...|
            ----------
```

So are there any solution to limit the height?

Ps. Sorry for my English.

Comment: There is no perfect solution for this, but you could count the line breaks and let a line break count for X letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function which reads every post and if have more than Xpx of height, you will add that 'more...' anchor and also limit the height.

Example:

```
$('post').each(function(){

    if($(this).height > 50){
         $(this).css('max-height', '50px');
         $(this).append('<a class="more">more....</a>');
    }
});
```

Then you make another function that listens the class `more` and if the click its done you quit the `max-height` property and the more anchor.

Comment: It is great but i want to cut the text if the height is above a value

Comment: Why don't you avoid the text cutting using CSS 'line-height'? For example, put 'line-height:12px' and then put the max-height according to the number of lines you want. Ex: 3*12=36px.

Comment: hmm the result seems to be the same so i think its ok if there is no better solution

Comment: With this method you don't crop your text so you don't have to apply another method to rescue the uncroped text when you click on the 'more...' button.

Maybe it's not the best solution but I think it's very easy to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution that will remove a single character from the content until it's height is as specified:

```
var maxHeight = 70;
var limiter = document.getElementById("limiter");
var height = limiter.clientHeight;
var content = limiter.innerText;
alert("Original Content:\n" + content);
var count = 0;
while (height > maxHeight && count < 100) {
    count++;
    content = content.substring(0, content.length - 1);
    limiter.innerText = content + " more...";
    height = limiter.clientHeight;
}
alert("Adjusted Content:\n" + content);
var html = limiter.innerHTML;
alert("Final HTML:\n" + html);
```

The `count` is there just to prevent getting stuck in an infinite loop, just in case. It is not necessary.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38p8hhve/